# .withSuccessHandler(updateName) not executing function in $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I based my code on the developer's [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms).  The code functions when $(document).ready is commented out but `updateName` fails to execute when uncommented.  How can google.script.run.withSuccessHandler() execute a function within $(document).ready?

index.html

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="myName" type="text" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateName)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
<!-- $(document).ready(function(){ -->
  function updateName(myName) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML = '<p> ' + myName + '</p>';
  }

<!-- )} -->
</script>
```

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  var myName = formObject.myName;
  Logger.log(formObject.myName);
  return myName
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you comment out `$(document).ready`, `updateName()` is defined with global scope. Otherwise, it's nested within `$(document).ready`.

Reference: [Nested Functions and Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures)

The purpose of `$(document).ready` is to enclose operations you want performed when the page loads and is ready. In your example, nothing would happen because all you've got is a function definition, but nothing to invoke it.